# Monitor doesn't show signal on onboard videocard

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, motherboard, hdmi

I have a Asus Sabertooth Z77 motherboard with the latest updated BIOS. This motherboard has an on-board graphics card with a HDMI interface.

I also have a video card itself, I've got an EVGA GTX 680 with also an HDMI interface.

This on-board graphics card works well, when I turn off my main video card (The GTX 680) in my device manager or boot up in safe-mode, I've got the on-board card working.

The interface that is being used is for some reason still coming from the GTX 680.

Now I bought 2 monitors, which are both connected via HDMI, one on my GTX 680 and one on the on-board video card itself.

The problem is that only the monitor which is connected to my GTX 680 is receiving signal. How does this come and how can I fix this?

I've already tried to update my drivers, re-insert and check the cable on the monitor which isn't working and enabled the iGPU Multi-Monitor option in my BIOS.

I'm 100% sure the monitor works, because when I connect both the monitors with DVI-D to the GTX 680 (it has more interfaces, but I want it connected via HDMI) both of the monitors work.

Comment: is your on board working single monitor connected ?

Comment: @mussdroid Yeah it is

Comment: check igpu enabled disabled ? Bios - Advanced Options - System Agent Configuration , igpu primary display ?

Comment: I enabled that option, the primary display is set to the pci port but tried both options and none worked

Comment: As I know you can't do dual HDMI ? Try VGA and HDMI or DVI and HDMI option

Comment: Why can't I do dual hdmi? I want audio on both monitors

Comment: I did that already

Comment: So it didn't work for you even with `Primary Display` set to [IGFX] and `iGPU Multi-Monitor` set to [Enabled] ?

Comment: @guest No it didn't work indeed and i'm 100% sure the cable is plugged in... how does htis come?

Comment: Have you installed Intel Graphics Driver and Management Engine Interface? What do you mean by "The interface that is being used is for some reason still coming from the GTX 680" ?

Comment: When I disable my GTX 680 in the device manager, and have both a cable plugged in the gtx 680 and the onboard card, the signal still comes from the GTX 680. For the driver, when I try to do it, it says my system isn't eligable.

Comment: I need to know if your iGPU is working. Is your CPU a Ivy Bridge Core i5/i7? If so, please connect only one monitor to motherboard (no dGPU), set BIOS `Primary Display` to [IGFX], then try install Graphics Driver again.

Comment: @guest It's an Ivy Bridge core I7. But that's the thing I tried, but then I just get no signal, I can't even get in the BIOS when i'm only plugging  a HDMI cable in my onboard video card.

Comment: Just to be sure, if you reset CMOS jumper, and still it gives no signal, I would say either your mobo or the iGPU on CPU chip is faulty.

Comment: @guest Do you mean by just unplugging my CMOS and re-inserting it?

Comment: hey how did it go?

Comment: @guest To be honest, I didn't try it out yet. I'm currently busy, but I bought an Displayport to HDMI converter which works great now. So I got 2 monitors working on 1 videocard. 

One thing I tried though was installing the driver, which didn't work. The installer litterly said my computer wasn't egible for the installation, with other words, how can I install the driver now? I tried different versions.

Comment: is there any unknown device in your device manager?

Comment: @guest Nope :( What could this possibly mean?

Comment: this probably means your iGPU isn't detected at all, and so the driver installation failed...

Comment: @guest Could it be broken? I've already installed the other drivers for my motherboard.

Comment: That is likely the case and I am unable to provide further assistance (which requires trial and error hardware swapping diagnosis...)